# selectize.js does not render options after ajax loading

Tags: ajax, selectize.js

I am trying to load items via `ajax` to `selectize.js` but it does not seem to work.

Api works fine, on success method is called but it does not render any item and it does not output a console given in render method.

Here's how it looks like (coffeescript)

```
FindUserDirective = ($http)->
  options =
    restrict: 'A'
    replace: false
    scope: true
    link: (scope, element, attrs)->
      $(element).selectize
        valueField: 'firstName'
        labelField: 'firstName'
        searchField: 'firstName'
        create: false
        render: option: (user, escape)->
          console.log user
          "<div>#{user.fullName}</div>"
        load: (query, callback)->
          if not query.length then callback()

          url = Routing.generate('api_cget_client', {uuid:config.studio.uuid})
          $http
            .get url
            .then(
              # on success
              (response)->
                callback response.data.users
                # this gives a beautiful array with users
              ,
              # on error
              (response)->
                callback()
            )
  options

application
  .directive('finduser' , FindUserDirective)
```

any idea?

Comment: can add an example json response?

Comment: Does it render when you re-focus the select element again?

Comment: I had same issue and just switched to [select2](https://select2.org/). :)

Comment: i used `$("#dom_id")[0].selectize.focus()` at the end. Seems to work - although feels hacky